# Problema em código de inserção ordenada de structs (registros) em arquivos

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, classificação

Estou fazendo um trabalho em que tenho que inserir structs em ordem alfabética em arquivos, em que as structs são políticos e os arquivos (que juntos formam uma lista encadeada) são os partidos. Estou com dificuldades na função de inserir os politicos de forma ordenada nos arquivos.

O algoritmo que eu fiz funciona (ou deveria funcionar) da seguinte maneira:

1 - O usuario escolhe o partido em que deseja inserir o político;

2 - O usuário preenche o nome e sobrenome do político;

3 - O programa insere o politico no arquivo do partido, caso este esteja vazio;

4 - Se o arquivo não estiver vazio, é criado um novo arquivo e são passados, em ordem, os elementos do arquivo antigo e o politico recém adicionado pelo usuário para o novo arquivo;

5 - O arquivo antigo é deletado e o novo arquivo recebe o nome do antigo;

O programa está inserindo os elementos na ordem correta, porém quando atinge determinado número (pequeno) de elementos, os novos sobrescrevem os antigos. Assim, o arquivo só fica com dois ou três políticos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

   typedef struct Politico
{
  char nome[30];
  int idade;
  int suspeita;   //de 0 a 3
}politico;

typedef struct Partido
{
  FILE* fp;   //file pointer
  char sigla[20];
  void* proximo;
}partido;

void inserirPoliticoOrdenado(partido** first)
{
  char sigla[20];
  char sobrenome[30];
  partido* party;
  politico novoPol;
  politico auxiliar;
  int inserirNovo = 0;
  politico menor;
  FILE* newfile;
  int contador = 0;
  int contador2 = 0;
  int teste;

  printf("Digite a sigla do partido em que deseja cadastrar o político\n");
  scanf("%s", sigla);

  getchar();

  party = buscarElemento(first, sigla);  //A função buscarElemento procura na lista encadeada o partido com a sigla digitada pelo usuário e retorna um ponteiro para esse partido. Se for necessário, posso postá-la aqui

  strcat(sigla, ".txt");

  if (party == NULL)
  {
    printf("O partido que procura não existe!!!\n");
  }

  if (party->fp == NULL)
  {
    printf("O partido que procura não está aberto.\n");
  }

  else
  {
    printf("\nDigite o primeiro nome do político que deseja adicionar.\n");
    fgets(novoPol.nome, 30, stdin);

    retirar_enter_de_fgets(novoPol.nome, 30);

    printf("\nDigite o sobrenome do político que deseja adicionar.\n");
    fgets(sobrenome, 30, stdin);

    retirar_enter_de_fgets(sobrenome, 30);

    adicionarEspacoAoFinalDeString(novoPol.nome);  //Para que ao concatenar o resultado não seja "NomeSobrenome", e sim "Nome Sobrenome"

    strcat(novoPol.nome, sobrenome);

    rewind(party->fp);  //Volta para o início do arquivo

    if (fread(&auxiliar, sizeof(politico), 1, party->fp) != 1) //Se o arquivo estiver vazio
    {
      rewind(party->fp);
      fwrite(&novoPol, sizeof(politico), 1, party->fp);
    }

    else //Se o arquivo não estiver vazio
    {
      newfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "wb+");  //Abre um novo arquivo

      rewind(party->fp);

      rewind(newfile);

      while (fread(&auxiliar, sizeof(politico), 1, party->fp) == 1)
      {
        if (inserirNovo == 0)  //Se o novo político já estiver inserido, esta variável será igual a 1
        {
          menor = novoPol;
        }

        else
        {
          menor = auxiliar;
        }

        if (strcmp(auxiliar.nome, menor.nome) <= 0)  //Se o nome do auxiliar for menor que o nome do menor
        {
          menor = auxiliar;

          fseek(newfile, (contador2) * sizeof(politico), SEEK_SET);

          fwrite(&menor, sizeof(politico), 1, newfile);  //Insere o politico de menor nome no novo arquivo

          contador++;

          contador2++;

          fseek(party->fp, contador * sizeof(politico), SEEK_SET); //Recomeçará a leitura na posição abaixo da anterior
        }

        else if (strcmp(menor.nome, novoPol.nome) == 0)  //Se o novo politico for o menor
        {
          fseek(newfile, (contador2) * sizeof(politico), SEEK_SET);  //Vai para a posição em que se deve inserir a struct no novo arquivo

          fwrite(&menor, sizeof(politico), 1, newfile);  //Escreve a struct no novo arquivo

          contador2++;

          fseek(party->fp, contador * sizeof(politico), SEEK_SET);

          inserirNovo = 1;
        }
      }

      if (inserirNovo == 0)  //Se a nova struct for "maior" que todas as outras, ela é inserida por último
      {
        fseek(newfile, (contador2) * sizeof(politico), SEEK_SET);

        fwrite(&novoPol, sizeof(politico), 1, newfile);
      }

      fclose(newfile);
      remove(sigla);   //Apaga o arquivo antigo
      rename("newfile.txt", sigla);   //Renomeia o novo arquivo de modo que este fique com o nome do arquivo antigo.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que tu nunca vai cair na segunda condição (tu já trata o caso de retornar zero na primeira).

```
    if (strcmp(auxiliar.nome, menor.nome) <= 0)
    {...}
    else if (strcmp(menor.nome, novoPol.nome) == 0) 
    {...}
```

Deveria ser algo:

```
    if (strcmp(auxiliar.nome, menor.nome) < 0)
    {...}
    else if (strcmp(menor.nome, novoPol.nome) == 0) 
    {...}
```

Uma dica para eficiência. Tu não precisa dos fseek que tu está usando, pois as estruturas FILE guardam onde você está no arquivo.